# Inner join core.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou precisando fazer um inner join para carregar em uma tabela, se fosse sem inner join eu faria desta forma:

```
PessoasServicos = await _context.PessoasServicos
            .Include(m => m.PlanosServicos).Where(m => m.PessoaId == id)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Segue como está o código da tabela:

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PessoasServicos.FirstOrDefault().Descricao)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PessoasServicos.FirstOrDefault().Tipo)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PessoasServicos.FirstOrDefault().Valor)
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model.PessoasServicos) {
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Descricao)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Tipo)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Valor)
    </th>
    <td>
      <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Editar</a>
      <button asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excluir</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  }
</table>
```

Como posso fazer o inner join ? Algum exemplo, ou alguma coisa que me ajuda, agradeço.

Comment: mas o `Include` já é o `inner join`, não ficou claro o que deseja

Comment: Preciso juntar a tabela PessoasServicos, que tem o campo PlanoId, com a tabela PlanosServicos.

Comment: mas e porque o `Include ` não está dando certo?

Comment: Não to conseguindo colocar a parte que eu preciso que é PessoasServicos.PlanoId = PlanosServicos.Id.  Dessa forma q eu to fazendo, ele não está aparecendo na tabela, o campo descrição, vem em branco.

Comment: Mas não precisa disso no `Where` o `Include` já faz essa parte sozinho do join. **Edição:** aah sim, mas então acho que é outro problema, rsrs, o campo descrição tem valor no BD? se possível, adicione os modelos(Classes)

Comment: Os outros campos da tabela, valor e tipo, está puxando normal, no caso a descrição é de PlanosServicos, o campo vem em branco.

Comment: Eu que estava passando o valor errado para a tabela @Barbetta, agora deu certo, obrigado.